# ADODB downloads an Excel stream, need to output this stream directly to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have code which downloads an Excel file using WinHTTPRequest.5.1

My current code saves the file as another Excel Workbook. I now want to save the download as a worksheet in the same workbook that is running the download code. How do I go about this? My current code is below:

```
WHTTP.Open "POST", fileUrl_XLSResult, False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.send POSTData_1

If WHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WHTTP.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile FilePath_1, 1
    oStream.Close
End If
```

As you can see, the above code downloads the Excel and saves a new workbook. How would I be able to save the Excel download as a worksheet in the 'main' workbook?

Comment: What have done so far? Post relevant parts of your code here

Comment: @Sam, I tried using the responseText method, but that outputs HTML code to a sheet

The code in the question already successfully downloads and saves the target workbook. I just need that workbook to be saved in an existing sheet on the main workbook. That would help me avoid downloading the workbook onto the hard disk and then reading data from it.

Comment: Have a look at Workbooks.Open

Comment: Odd question. If you need some specific sheet, open the workbook and copy it to your target workbook.